# Dynamically allocate variables

Tags: python, variables, namespaces, global-variables

I have a dictionary that contains variable names and their corresponding values I would like to allocate dynamically

```
dict_ = {'var1':'cvx.Variable(3)', 'var2':'3'}
```

In my code I then do

```
for k,v in dict_.iteritems():
    exec("global %s;%s=%s" % (k,k,v))
    print k, type(k)
```

For the integer variable this works and I get 3 type 'int', however for var1 ( import cvxpy as cvx) I get k type 'str'. Where I would want to get

```
class 'cvxpy.expressions.variables.variable.Variable'
```

Any advise what I am doing wrong ?

EDIT: I am receiving the dictionary entries as a string input like

```
"var1 = cvx.Variable(3),var2 = 3"
```

which I then transform into the dictionary

Comment: You already have the variables and their values in a dictionary. Why go to so much effort to put them into another dictionary? Just write your code to use the dictionary instead of global variables.

Comment: _why_  would you want to do this?

Comment: Because you made it a string... Try this: dict_ = {'var1':cvx.Variable(3), 'var2':'3'}

Comment: `k` is a reference to the string `'var1'`; it is not `var1` itself.

Comment: As @chepner says, `k` is the key in `dict_` which is defined as `str` (`'var1'` and `'var2'` in your example, notice the pairs of `'`). Therefore, I also doubt that _for the integer variable this works and [you] get 3 type 'int'_. I am pretty sure that `print k, type(k)` writes `var1` and `str`  and `var2` and `str` to stdout.

Answer (score 1):

## Why you should *not* use non-string `dict_` values:

As stated in [its documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations), the `%` operator calls the `str()` built-in function when used with the `%s` format.

When `str()` is called on a `cvxpy.Variable` instance, it returns a string with the format `varX` where `X` is an integer (the index of the created variable in memory, I suppose):

```
>>> import cvxpy
>>> x = cvxpy.Variable(3)
>>> str(x)
'var0'
```

Unfortunately, this format happens to be the naming convension used by the string you receive for its variables.

Defining `dict_ = {'var1':cvx.Variable(3), 'var2':3}` will not only *not* solve your issue but may silently succeed as the value at `dict_['var1']`, passed to `str()`, may return a `varX` value on the right side of the assignment that you build with `%` that refers to an existing variable (declared before the loop or through the `global` passed to `exec()`).

---

Instead, you code should work and your issue certainly lies outside of what you are sharing with us.

As an example, I run the following code on my machine (Python 2.7.12):

```
>>> import cvxpy
>>> cvxpy.__version__
'1.0.6'
>>> d = {'var1': 'cvxpy.Variable(3)', 'var2': '3'}
>>> for k, v in d.iteritems():
...     s = 'global %s; %s = %s' % (k, k, v)
...     print s
...     exec(s)
...
global var1; var1 = cvxpy.Variable(3)
global var2; var2 = 3
>>> print var1, type(var1)
var0 <class 'cvxpy.expressions.variable.Variable'>
>>> print var2, type(var2)
3 <type 'int'>
```

Notice that `print var1` prints `var0` as explained above!

It looks like most of the comments and the solution here seem to contain some confusion between the running code, the string parsing and the `exec`uted code: anything that you are going to `exec` *should* be a `str`! If it is not then it will become a `str` by directly or indirectly calling the `str()` built-in (as done by your call to `%`) because `exec` takes a string.

---

If the string is already properly formatted as you suggest, have you considered doing something like the following?

```
str_in = "var1 = cvx.Variable(3),var2 = 3"
exec(str_in.replace(',', ';'))
```

**NB**: Here, I make the assumption that you are at the proper scope to not require the `global` but a bit more string parsing (`split`, `strip`, ...) would make it trivial to first declare the variables as `global`s.

Comment: You are correct in your statement regarding the `%s` formatting, however, if he wants to force everything to `global` scope, he can use the `globals().update(<dict>)` method to add variables to the mapping. Check my edit, and +1 for the catch regarding the original purpose of the question

Answer (score 0):

When you are putting those variables in the dictionary, you are explicitly setting them as strings. Do this instead:

```
dict_ = {'var1':cvx.Variable(3), 'var2':3}
```

Assuming you want `var2` to be `int` rather than `str`. Otherwise, when you wrap the value for `var1` in quotes, it will default to a stringType

EDIT:
PicTo is correct regarding your implementation, because you are using `%s` formatting, you are automatically converting your variable to a stringType. What may be more along the lines of what you're looking for is this:

```
dict_ = {'var1':cvx.Variable(3), 'var2':3}

globals().update(dict_)
```

That will put the variables in global scope *and* keep your types consistent, assuming you want the variables in global scope. If you don't, `locals()` supports the same paradigm

Example:

```
>>> mydict = {'var1':3, 'var2': "happystring"}
>>> globals().update(dict_)
>>> var1
3
>>> var2
'happystring'
```

Comment: Keep in mind that this solution still creates (and stores) the desired variables twice: once in the values of `dict_` and once (a copy) in `globals()`. Most of the time, this won't be an issue but if you are playing with `cvxpy`, it might be.

Comment: Ah so does the reference not persist into `globals`?

Comment: Yes, it is a shallow copy, indeed. Good idea of using `globals().update`, by the way!